# CASE statement using 2 different columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Can someone please help me fix the below code?

```
CASE Table1.Column1   
                WHEN 'a' THEN '1'
CASE Table2.Column2 
                WHEN 'b' THEN '2'
                WHEN 'c' THEN '3'

                ELSE '4'
    END AS [Test],
```

I am trying to get values in one new column (Test) from Table1.Column1 and Table2.Column2 column.
Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's another format for `CASE` that handles this:

```
CASE WHEN Table1.Column1 = 'a' THEN '1'
     WHEN Table2.Column2 = 'b' THEN '2'
     WHEN Table2.Column2 = 'c' THEN '3'
     ELSE '4'
END AS [Test],
```

This format also allows for multiple conditions like: `WHEN a.col1 = 1 AND b.col1 = 2 THEN 'something'`, which can be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to create "dictionary" table:

```
DECLARE @dictTable TABLE(MyReplacement INT, MyKey VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO @dictTable (MyReplacement, MyKey)
VALUES(1, 'a'), (2, 'b')...
```

Then

```
SELECT t1.<Fields_List>, t2.<Fields_List>, t3.MyReplacement
FROM Table1 AS t1 (INNER|LEFT|RIGHT) JOIN Table2 AS t2 ON t1.Key = t2.ForeignKey
    LEFT JOIN @dictTable  AS t3 ON t1.Column1 = t2.MyKey AND t2.Column2 = t2.MyKey
```

Comment: Above code worked so I'll go ahead and use that. Thanks.